# How do I switch my Gradle from JRE to JDK

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I have a program that requires gradle to run on jdk, but it keeps running on jre, and I do not know how to stop it. I have tried uninstalling jre, then both jre and jdk and reinstalling jdk only, but none of this has worked.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have configured it otherwise, Gradle will run all Java related tasks using the JVM that runs Gradle itself.

So the simpler approach is to make sure that your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable points to a JDK and start Gradle with it.